# Intel Matrix Storage Manager on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: raid, storage, windows-server-2008-r2

I am currently setting up a Windows Server 2008 R2 with Intel RAID.

Is there a version of `Intel Matrix Storage Manager` that runs on Windows Server 2008 R2?

All help is more than appreciated!

Comment: Matrix Storage Manager has been renamed Rapid Storage Technology... you might get greater success Googling "Rapid Storage Technology" :) Jerome has given you the link to download RST, so all should be fine! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure there is, take a look at [Intel.com](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Chipsets&ProductLine=Chipset+Software&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE+Rapid+Storage+Technology).

I'm using IMSM for years now. First on 2k3 now on 2k8R2.

Answer (score 1):

**Additional info**

There are two versions available

- [Intel Rapid Storage Technology](http://www.win-lite.de/wbb/board195-windows-7/board198-win7-treiber/3141-intel-r-rapid-storage-technologie-aktuell-rst-e-v11-7-0-1013-whql/) (Intel RST)
- [Intel Rapid Storage Technology enterprise](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Software+Products&ProductLine=Chipset+Software&ProductProduct=Intel%c2%ae+Rapid+Storage+Technology+enterprise+(Intel%c2%ae+RSTe)) (Intel RSTe)
- Here are two [repositories](http://www.win-lite.de/wbb/board195-windows-7/board198-win7-treiber/3141-intel-r-rapid-storage-technologie-aktuell-rst-e-v11-7-0-1013-whql/) for [older RST & RSTe](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.computerbase.de%2Fdownloads%2Ftreiber%2Fmainboards%2Fintel-rapid-storage-technologie%2F) drivers

**What you should know**

- its possible to switch from RST (isStor.sys) to RSTe (iaStorA.sys & iaStorF.sys)  and back
- Both versions support trim in RAID setups [since v11.0](http://www.anandtech.com/show/6161/intel-brings-trim-to-raid0-ssd-arrays-on-7series-motherboards-we-test-it)
- Here is Intel's [overview table](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=http://www.intel.com/support/de/chipsets/imsm/sb/cs-022304.htm?wapkw) what RAID modes on which IO Controller Hub (ICH) are supported
- you can check what driver your system is using with this portable tool [DriveControllerInfo](http://download.orbmu2k.de/files/DriveControllerInfo.zip)
- you can check if trim [is enabled](https://superuser.com/a/517052/50173) with this little command line programm

Despite that note that there is [currently an exception](http://www.hardwarecanucks.com/news/storage-news/intels-trim-support-for-raid-configurations-coming-soon-to-x79/) with X79 boards (Aug 2012)

> Current RSTe drivers specific to X79 do NOT support TRIM on RAID 0, but an updated RST driver version coming soon will add support for X79 based systems, including the TRIM on RAID 0 feature.