# How can i see if my SSD needs to have TRIM run against it?

Tags: ssd, trim, disk-monitoring

I'm getting intermittent performance issues with my intel SSD (X25-M 160GB). every few days the Disk Queue Length gets very high and the machine effectively locks up - queue length being 10 to 15 for about 30 seconds.

Is there a way to see if the SSD needs to have TRIM run against it?  I.e. some way to see how many blocks are marked as dirty.  I have got the Intel SSD optimizer which will manually run TRIM but would like to know for sure this is solving the problem - always a pain with intermittent bugs!

System is running Win 7 64 bit.  The workload it seems to have most problems with a compilation of a large solution - it's writing a high number of small files (approx 10K)

Update:

- The SSD is Intel SSDSA2M 160G2GC
- Firmware version is 2CV102M3 (previously was 2CV102HD)
- Driver is the default MS driver 6.1.7600.16385

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I see if Windows 7 is using TRIM for my SSD drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/64121/how-can-i-see-if-windows-7-is-using-trim-for-my-ssd-drive)

Comment: This question is more about how you see the state of the SSD than how you enable TRIM.  I can force TRIM to run if I need to but I'd like to be sure that it solves the problem before I do it all our dev machines.  Knowing how much of the SSD requires TRIMing would give me some evidence that a manual TRIM solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issues as you before. It was actually not due to the TRIM but rather Intel's Rapid Storage Technology. I had this software installed on my laptop which used a Crucial M4 128GB Sata3 SSD. It was a new SSD and had no previous data written on it. However, after installing the RST software from Intel, it would appear that the system would freeze for 30 seconds. Within the same OS install, uninstalling the RST solved the problem. The only time I use the RST software is if I'm using my SSD with a z68 board and SRT (Smart Response Technology (SSD Caching)).

Comment: Interesting, I'm not using Intel's RST, just the default MS driver.  Have added more details to the question about the ssd, firmware and driver

Comment: Check out intels toolbox for SSDs. http://downloadmirror.intel.com/18455/eng/Intel%20SSD%20Toolbox%20-%20v3.0.1.exe

Comment: I've got the toolbox (that's how I can force a TRIM on demand) and couldn't see any information about the state of the drive relating to TRIM.  Is there something in the depths of SMART or elsewhere that can show me how much the drive needs TRIM to be run?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get this info. Only if Intel will do that, because there is no any documentation that describes the internal commands of SSD. However, your problem can be in free space. ssd manufacturers recommends to have 20-30% of free space on the drive. Also, how many writes you have on SSD?

Comment: I've got about 60GB free of 149GB.  Not sure what you mean about the wires?  It's a shame if this data is not exposed, it would be useful to know for sure whether it is the problem or not.

Comment: Not a wires, sorry! Writes. How many writes do you have on SSD. If you'll write about 60gb on SSD(in your case) - you should use trim.