# Does using 'Sleep' affect the SSD?

Tags: ssd, sleep, ultrabook

I have a Windows 8 SSD-*only* Ultrabook, and I was wondering if using the '**Sleep**' mode affects the SSD negatively?
Thank you,
Mark

Comment: I can't imagine why it would.

Comment: *affects* in what way? This question is pretty broad..

Comment: @Raystafarian - I know I am assuming, but I read affects SSD negatively as lifespan/endurance, performance, and full failure caused by sleep mode.

Comment: Disabling the `hyberfile.sys` is more for [saving some SSD space](http://superuser.com/questions/624979/what-adjustments-should-be-done-for-a-ssd/625024#625024) than reducing write operations. So, no, this tweak does not affect your SSD lifespan.

Answer (score 3):

Well if you are refering to lifespan (reduction) due to excessive writes, than no.

In sleep mode the laptops state is held in RAM, then power use is minimized to all components.

Hibernation is another story as the computer's state is writen to the drive (SSD in your case) and powered down. There are many suggestions to never use hibernation with an SSD and in fact, would be better to power down the system (change "what happens when I close the cover" to shut down) because the start up is pretty fast compared to a platter drive.

Comment: I was referring to that, yes. Thank you VERY much for the useful answer, AND the extra useful info about hibernation! Awesome.

Comment: @mark - check this out for some other tweaks on SSDs. Good general advice, but your Ultrabook may already be set up pretty well, but a good read. http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/10/maximizing-the-lifetime-of-your-ssd/ as posted by Tom Wijsman

Answer (score 1):

No! The only thing that has any effect on the SSD is excessive write cycles.  If the SSD and  the OS support TRIM the negative effect of excessive writes is reduced.  Windows 7 & 8 support TRIM.  Write cycles will eventually wear out spots in memory.  However, the drive is design to automatically replace these bad spots with spares as soon as a bad location is discovered.