# Move my existing Windows installation onto a SSD

Tags: windows, ssd, windows-8.1, disk-image, macrium

I've just bought a 240Gb SSD, while my existing laptop hard drive is 1Tb.

I have made a 'clean-ish' version of Windows 8.1 from the 1Tb drive and saved a Macrium Reflect image of this partition - Can I simply restore this partition onto the new 240Gb SSD drive (note this new 'clean' partition is less than 100Gb) using my Macrium Reflect image?

Comment: Hint: Select the correct target alignment option `Vista/7/SSD`. Afterwards you should check if Macrium Reflect has used a proper alignment size with [AS SSD benchmark or a similar tool](http://superuser.com/a/625024/50173)

Comment: why do people downgrade a question but not say why?!? (sigh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming back to a really old answer.. for some reason Macrium didn't work so I found the equivalent by Acronis.

Acronis Image Backup did all what I wanted (and more)... SSD is running Windows perfectly thanks to Acronis, i'd recommend it.

Comment: When you say Macrium didn't work... how exactly did it fail?

Comment: Macrium wasn't able to resize the partitions dynamically for some reason with the SSD but the Acronis did - this is a very old question so I am guessing Macrium works fine now

Answer (score 1):

For a free option you can

1. Use [Clonezilla Live](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php) to clone your old hard drive onto your new SSD (either mounted internally as a second drive, or externally via a USB caddy).
2. If the SSD is larger you can increase the partition size from within Windows, though you may need to use a tool such as the [free edition of AOMEI Partition Manager](https://www.disk-partition.com/free-partition-manager.html) to move the recovery partition out of the way so you can extend your main partition.
3. [ensure that your new SSD's partition is aligned correctly](https://superuser.com/questions/718505/is-my-ssd-disk-aligned-to-4k-sectors-and-if-not-how-do-i-fix-it) for maximum SSD performance using a tool such as the [free version of EaseUS](https://www.easeus.com/partition-manager/epm-free.html) to align to 4k.
4. Ensure that your new SSD is operating under [AHCI mode in the BIOS](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2154735/change-ssd-ahci-mode.html).

Comment: Why did someone downvote this?!? I've given it a +1 as it has useful information to me