# How to know in Windows 8 if TRIM is enabled in SSD hard drive?

Tags: windows-8, ssd, trim

I have a SSD drive and Windows 8 installed.

Where can I find if my drive has trim activated?

Comment: A search for the title of your question gives the following as the first link - [How to Check and Enable or Disable SSD TRIM Support in Windows 7 and Windows 8](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/39569-trim-support-ssd-check-enable-disable.html)

Comment: Although ["answered for Windows 7"](http://superuser.com/questions/64121/how-can-i-see-if-windows-7-is-using-trim-for-my-ssd-drive?rq=1) the answer still applies

Answer (score 1):

Download and run the Program [Trimcheck](http://files.thecybershadow.net/trimcheck/) on the SSD. The program will set up a test by creating and deleting a file with unique contents, then (on the second run) checks if the data is still accessible at the file's previous location. If TRIM works it shows zeros for the file:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 should detect an SSD drive and automatically enable TRIM.

I find the easiest way to be sure is to click start > type 'defrag' > load the Windows defrag tool and see if it has detected the solid state drive in which case it will state 'Never Run' meaning it knows the drive type and knows how to care for it best.